# Why am I getting a "Duplicate symbol" linker error in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I know what duplicate symbol linker error means, but in my case I don't know how I'm getting it. I have the following file, which defines some simple globals

```
// defines.h

#ifndef _DEFINES_H
#define _DEFINES_H

BOOL useTestCode = YES;

#endif
```

Then I import it in two *.m files, and use the global.

```
// someFile1.m
#import "defines.h"

- (void)foo
{
    if (useTestCode) {
        NSLog(@"Using test code");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"NOT Using test code");
    }
}

// someFile2.m
#import "defines.h"

- (void)foo
{
    if (useTestCode) {
        NSLog(@"Using test code");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"NOT Using test code");
    }
}
```

If I comment out one of the #import "defines.h" statement in either file, I don't get the duplicate symbol linker error, but of course the corresponding *.m file will fail to compile. Why am I getting the duplicate symbol linker error? How do I solve it in iOS 7?

Here is the linker error message. It's literally for the simple code above.

duplicate symbol _useTestCode in:
    /Users/cfouts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DupSymbol-bnfownlxdoyqelbhxzpyaaitfshy/Build/Intermediates/DupSymbol.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DupSymbol.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DSsomeFile2.o
    /Users/cfouts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DupSymbol-bnfownlxdoyqelbhxzpyaaitfshy/Build/Intermediates/DupSymbol.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DupSymbol.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DSsomeFile1.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What is the link error message? Copy the message to your question. In particular, what is the duplicate symbol.

Comment: Also, include "defines.h" in your question if it is small enough.

Comment: You should show full error log. I think xcode will show duplicated symbols

Answer (score 2):

in your header you have

```
BOOL useTestCode = YES;
```

which is copied to every .m file that includes it so you have multiple `useTestCode` symbols

you need to change the header to contain

```
extern BOOL useTestCode;
```

and in **one** .m file, define the variable

```
BOOL useTestCode = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Though Bryan C's answer is one solution, and it gave me a clue, I like this better.

```
// defines.h

#ifndef _DEFINES_H
#define _DEFINES_H

static BOOL useTestCode = YES;

#endif
```